# Additional property is not allowed in Helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm

Since I added some additonal initContainers to my Airflow helm chart [(link)](https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/main/chart), I was trying to set a default `initContainerResources` to my helm values and deployment yaml:

- values.yaml

```
# Airflow scheduler settings
scheduler:
  
  initContainerResources:
    resources: 
     limits:
      cpu: 200m
      memory: 255Mi
     requests:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 128Mi
```

- .. and deployment.yaml

```
...
        - name: scheduler-add-init1
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: False
          resources:
{{ toYaml .Values.scheduler.initContainerResources.resources | indent 12 }}
...
```

However, when I try to render the files with helm template, I get:

> Error: values don't meet the specifications of the schema(s) in the
> following chart(s): airflow:
>
> - scheduler: Additional property initContainerResources is not allowed

My goal was to define the init containers resources together but independent from the scheduler container. What´s wrong with my setup?

Comment: just posted my findings, both answers did not really solved the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out I had the schema validation process blocking me from adding additional parameters. Just added the desired key to the schema and it worked:

values.schema.json

```
                "initContainerResources": {
                    "description": "Add default ressources to all init containers of scheduler.",
                    "type": "object",
                    "default": "See values.yaml"
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

`resources: {{ toYaml .Values.scheduler.initContainerResources.resources | indent 12 }}`

Try to put:

`resources: {{ $.Values.scheduler.initContainerResources.resources }}`